# ../aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/NLLLoss2d.cu:104: nll_loss2d_forward_kernel: block: [4,0,0], thread: [586,0,0] Assertion `t >= 0 && t < n_classes` failed

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network, google-colaboratory

I get this error when I run this command: `!python Models/KiU-Net/LiTS/train.py` (training my neural network on Google Colab Pro in Python and Windows 10).

I tried to run this command: `!python Models/KiU-Net/LiTS/train.py -Xcompiler -fno-gnu-unique`, but I still got the same error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/visdom/__init__.py", line 692, in _send
    return self._handle_post(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/visdom/__init__.py", line 656, in _handle_post
    r = self.session.post(url, data=data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 578, in post
    return self.request('POST', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 530, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 643, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 516, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=666): Max retries exceeded with url: /update (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f1fa000dee0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
epoch:0, step:0, loss1:1.171, loss2:1.417, loss3:1.201, loss4:1.182, loss:2.4318742752075195 time:0.077 min
../aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/NLLLoss2d.cu:104: nll_loss2d_forward_kernel: block: [15,0,0], thread: [303,0,0] Assertion `t >= 0 && t < n_classes` failed.
../aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/NLLLoss2d.cu:104: nll_loss2d_forward_kernel: block: [7,0,0], thread: [304,0,0] Assertion `t >= 0 && t < n_classes` failed.
../aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/NLLLoss2d.cu:104: nll_loss2d_forward_kernel: block: [7,0,0], thread: [817,0,0] Assertion `t >= 0 && t < n_classes` failed.
../aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/NLLLoss2d.cu:104: nll_loss2d_forward_kernel: block: [15,0,0], thread: [48,0,0] Assertion `t >= 0 && t < n_classes` failed.
../aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/NLLLoss2d.cu:104: nll_loss2d_forward_kernel: block: [22,0,0], thread: [47,0,0] Assertion `t >= 0 && t < n_classes` failed.
../aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/NLLLoss2d.cu:104: nll_loss2d_forward_kernel: block: [11,0,0], thread: [845,0,0] Assertion `t >= 0 && t < n_classes` failed.
../aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/NLLLoss2d.cu:104: nll_loss2d_forward_kernel: block: [8,0,0], thread: [562,0,0] Assertion `t >= 0 && t < n_classes` failed.
../aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/NLLLoss2d.cu:104: nll_loss2d_forward_kernel: block: [4,0,0], thread: [586,0,0] Assertion `t >= 0 && t < n_classes` failed.
```

This is the training file (*train.py*) where I train a convolutional neural network, calculating the loss (cross-entropy loss) and making backpropagation to update the weights:

```
import os
from time import time

import numpy as np

import torch
import torch.backends.cudnn as cudnn
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader

from visdom import Visdom

from dataset.dataset import Dataset

from loss.Dice import DiceLoss
from loss.ELDice import ELDiceLoss
from loss.WBCE import WCELoss
from loss.Jaccard import JaccardLoss
from loss.SS import SSLoss
from loss.Tversky import TverskyLoss
from loss.Hybrid import HybridLoss
from loss.BCE import BCELoss

from net.models import net

import parameter as para

viz = Visdom(port=666)
step_list = [0]
win = viz.line(X=np.array([0]), Y=np.array([1.0]), opts=dict(title='loss'))


os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = para.gpu
cudnn.benchmark = para.cudnn_benchmark


net = torch.nn.DataParallel(net).cuda()
net.train()

print(para.training_set_path)
train_ds = Dataset(os.path.join(para.train_ct_path, 'ct'), os.path.join(para.train_seg_path, 'seg'))


train_dl = DataLoader(train_ds, para.batch_size, True, num_workers=para.num_workers, pin_memory=para.pin_memory)


loss_func_list = [DiceLoss(), ELDiceLoss(), WCELoss(), JaccardLoss(), SSLoss(), TverskyLoss(), HybridLoss(), BCELoss()]
loss_func = loss_func_list[5]


opt = torch.optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr=para.learning_rate, capturable=True)
#opt = torch.optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr=para.learning_rate)

lr_decay = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.MultiStepLR(opt, para.learning_rate_decay)


alpha = para.alpha

start = time()



for epoch in range(para.Epoch):

    lr_decay.step()

    mean_loss = []

    for step, (ct, seg) in enumerate(train_dl):


        ct = ct.cuda()
        seg = seg.cuda()


        # print(f"seg unique: {torch.unique(seg)}")

        
        outputs = net(ct)
        # print(len(outputs))
        loss1 = loss_func(outputs[0], seg)
        loss2 = loss_func(outputs[1], seg)
        loss3 = loss_func(outputs[2], seg)
        loss4 = loss_func(outputs[3], seg)

        loss = (loss1 + loss2 + loss3) * alpha + loss4

        mean_loss.append(loss4.item())

        opt.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        #print("Capturing:", torch.cuda.is_current_stream_capturing())
        opt.step()


        if step % 5 == 0:
            
            step_list.append(step_list[-1] + 1)
            viz.line(X=np.array([step_list[-1]]), Y=np.array([loss4.item()]), win=win, update='append')
            
            print('epoch:{}, step:{}, loss1:{:.3f}, loss2:{:.3f}, loss3:{:.3f}, loss4:{:.3f}, loss:{} time:{:.3f} min'
                  .format(epoch, step, loss1.item(), loss2.item(), loss3.item(), loss4.item(), loss, (time() - start) / 60))

    mean_loss = sum(mean_loss) / len(mean_loss)

   
    if epoch % 50 == 0 :

        
        torch.save(net.state_dict(), '/content/drive/MyDrive/CS/Models/KiU-Net/LiTS/saved_networks/net{}-{:.3f}-{:.3f}.pth'.format(epoch, loss, mean_loss))

    
    if epoch % 40 == 0 and epoch != 0:
        alpha *= 0.8
```

This is my model (*net.py*). It is a convolutional neural network (the input size is equal to the output size) to make a multiclass segmentation of 3 classes: background, liver, and tumor of medical images (LiTS, liver tumor segmentation benchmark):

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.append(os.path.split(sys.path[0])[0])

import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

import parameter as para

class segnet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, training):
        super(segnet, self).__init__()
        self.training = training
        self.encoder1 = nn.Conv3d(1, 32, 3, stride=1, padding=1)  # b, 16, 10, 10
        self.encoder2 = nn.Conv3d(32, 64, 3, stride=1, padding=1)  # b, 8, 3, 3
        self.encoder3 = nn.Conv3d(64, 128, 3, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.encoder4 = nn.Conv3d(128, 256, 3, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.encoder5 = nn.Conv3d(256, 512, 3, stride=1, padding=1)
        
        self.decoder1 = nn.Conv3d(512, 256, 3, stride=1,padding=1)  # b, 16, 5, 5
        self.decoder2 = nn.Conv3d(256, 128, 3, stride=1, padding=1)  # b, 8, 15, 1
        self.decoder3 = nn.Conv3d(128, 64, 3, stride=1, padding=1)  # b, 1, 28, 28
        self.decoder4 = nn.Conv3d(64, 32, 3, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.decoder5 = nn.Conv3d(32, 3, 3, stride=1, padding=1) # self.decoder5 =   nn.Conv3d(32, 2, 3, stride=1, padding=1)
                                #(32, 3...
        self.map4 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv3d(3, 3, 1, 1), #nn.Conv3d(2, 1, 1, 1) / nn.Conv3d(3, 3, 1, 1)
            nn.Upsample(scale_factor=(1, 1, 1), mode='trilinear'), # nn.Upsample(scale_factor=(1, 2, 2), mode='trilinear')
            nn.Sigmoid()
        )

        # 128*128 尺度下的映射
        self.map3 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv3d(64, 3, 1, 1), #nn.Conv3d(64, 1, 1, 1) / nn.Conv3d(64, 3, 1, 1)
            nn.Upsample(scale_factor=(4, 4, 4), mode='trilinear'), #nn.Upsample(scale_factor=(4, 8, 8), mode='trilinear')
            nn.Sigmoid()
        )

        # 64*64 尺度下的映射
        self.map2 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv3d(128, 3, 1, 1), #nn.Conv3d(128, 1, 1, 1) / nn.Conv3d(128, 3, 1, 1)
            nn.Upsample(scale_factor=(8, 8, 8), mode='trilinear'), #nn.Upsample(scale_factor=(8, 16, 16), mode='trilinear')
            nn.Sigmoid()
        )

        # 32*32 尺度下的映射
        self.map1 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv3d(256, 3, 1, 1), #nn.Conv3d(256, 1, 1, 1) / nn.Conv3d(256, 3, 1, 1)
            nn.Upsample(scale_factor=(16, 16, 16), mode='trilinear'), #nn.Upsample(scale_factor=(16, 32, 32), mode='trilinear'),
            nn.Sigmoid()
        )

        self.soft = nn.Softmax(dim = 1) #self.soft = nn.Softmax(dim = 1)

    def forward(self, x):
        out = F.relu(F.max_pool3d(self.encoder1(x),2,2))
        t1 = out
        out = F.relu(F.max_pool3d(self.encoder2(out),2,2))
        t2 = out
        out = F.relu(F.max_pool3d(self.encoder3(out),2,2))
        t3 = out
        out = F.relu(F.max_pool3d(self.encoder4(out),2,2))
        t4 = out
        out = F.relu(F.max_pool3d(self.encoder5(out),2,2))
        
        # t2 = out
        out = F.relu(F.interpolate(self.decoder1(out),scale_factor=(2,2,2),mode ='trilinear'))
        # print(out.shape,t4.shape)
        out = torch.add(F.pad(out,[0,0,0,0,0,1]),t4)
        output1 = self.map1(out)
        out = F.relu(F.interpolate(self.decoder2(out),scale_factor=(2,2,2),mode ='trilinear'))
        # out = torch.add(out,t3)
        output2 = self.map2(out)
        out = F.relu(F.interpolate(self.decoder3(out),scale_factor=(2,2,2),mode ='trilinear'))
        # out = torch.add(out,t2)
        output3 = self.map3(out)
        out = F.relu(F.interpolate(self.decoder4(out),scale_factor=(2,2,2),mode ='trilinear'))
        # out = torch.add(out,t1)
        
        out = F.relu(F.interpolate(self.decoder5(out),scale_factor=(2,2,2),mode ='trilinear'))
        output4 = self.map4(out)
        # print(out.shape)
        # print(output1.shape,output2.shape,output3.shape,output4.shape)
        if self.training is True:
            return output1, output2, output3, output4
        else:
            return output4

def init(module):
    if isinstance(module, nn.Conv3d) or isinstance(module, nn.ConvTranspose3d):
        nn.init.kaiming_normal_(module.weight.data, 0.25)
        nn.init.constant_(module.bias.data, 0)


net = segnet(training=True)
# net = kiunet_org(training=True)
net.apply(init)

# 计算网络参数
print('net total parameters:', sum(param.numel() for param in net.parameters()))
```

This is the file where I calculate cross-entropy loss (*Tversky.py*):

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

class TverskyLoss(nn.Module):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ce_loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(reduction='mean')

    def forward(self, pred, target):
        pred = pred.squeeze(dim=1) # pred.size() == target.size()
        output = self.ce_loss(pred, target.to(torch.int64))
        return output
```

Comment: I think the error is in Tversky.py when calculating the Cross Entropy Loss (which is something I do not understand because with MSE Loss works). The shape is of pred is: `torch.Size([1, 3, 48, 256, 256])` and the shape of target is:
`torch.Size([1, 48, 256, 256])`. Also, it is a multiclass segmentation task in medical images, where in target the classes are: 0-> background, 1-> liver and 2-> tumor.